# Wordpress-like Subscription

Tags: users, plugins, form

Wordpress has a great feature which allows visitors to sign up to receive email notifications whenever there's an update to the site. I'd like to emulate this functionality.

I'm aware of Postmaster, Brief, Sprout Forms, Sprout Emails, MailChimp Subscribe and have read through similar discussions and solutions here on the Craft SE - but nothing that would get me all the way there.

Requirements would be:

- Ability to sign up per channel via email (a form per channel)
- Confirm email address (double opt-in)
- No (Craft member) registration necessary
- Ability to unsubscribe
- Auto send email notification when new entry is posted

Is there a current solution that could tick all these boxes? If not, would this a possible to build as a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this carefully from a subscriber's perspective. i.e. If I received an email every time something was published, I may consider unsubscribing very quickly.

An alternative which I've found works very well is to send email updates on a **regular basis** - that way your subscribers have an expectation of the frequency.

We've used Campaign Monitor to automatically pull content from a RSS template and then send an email newsletter as well. You also have the flexibility to curate the entries as you see fit.

Have a look at this page/video: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/new-features/2012/03/one-click-content/

> Ability to sign up per channel via email (a form per channel)

You can create separate (subscriber) lists within Campaign Monitor, for each Channel/Section

> Confirm email address (double opt-in)
>
> No (site) registration necessary
>
> Ability to unsubscribe

These are all possible.

> Auto send email notification when new entry is posted

Automation is also possible.

Hopefully that makes sense - let us know your thoughts?

Comment: It's real low volume of entries - a school site where parents can subscribe to their childs class blog - so I'm not too concerned about frequency. But I do want the option for them to unsubscribe. The Campaign Monitor + RSS looks good - but looks like sending has to be done manually. Is there a way I could automate it?

Comment: You can actually [automate](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=212) those e-mails with Campaign Monitor using whatever frequency you want.  I'm a fan of MailChimp as well, which has similar [functionality](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/rss-in-campaigns/create-an-rss-campaign).